# Confusion of using "." notation with __index and namespace in Lua

Tags: lua, namespaces, metatable, meta-method

I am confused of the following two syntaxes using "."

1. From what I understand, `__index` is called when a key doesn't exist in a table but exists in its metatable.  So why does the list table call `__index` and then assign itself  to `list.__index`?

   ```
   list = {}
   list.__index = list

   setmetatable(list, { __call = function(_, ...)
   local t = setmetatable({length = 0}, list)
     for _, v in ipairs{...} do t:push(v) end
     return t
   end })

   function list:push(t)
     if self.last then
       self.last._next = t
       t._prev = self.last
       self.last = t
     else
      self.first = t
      self.last = t
     end
     self.length = self.length + 1
   end 
     .
     .
     .
   local l = list({ 2 }, {3}, {4}, { 5 })
   ```
2. Does `Window.mt` simply create a table?  Why do we need `Window = {}` as a namespace here?

   ```
   Window = {}  -- create a namespace    
   Window.mt = {}  -- create a metatable
   Window.prototype = {x=0, y=0, width=100, height=100, } 

   function Window.new (o)  
       setmetatable(o, Window.mt)
       return o
   end

   Window.mt.__index = function (table, key)
       return Window.prototype[key]
   end

   w = Window.new{x=10, y=20}
   print(w.width)    --> 100
   ```

Comment: `.` is used to access table fields, what exactly don't you understand? The metamethod `__index`? Complete your question.

Comment: Did you have a look at http://lua-users.org/wiki/MetatableEvents?

Comment: Exactly what things in the code are you confused about? You mention `.` and `__call` in the title but in the question body you ask about `__index` and table construction. You'll have to focus your question better because atm it's all over the place. Are you having trouble understanding how all these features work together?

Comment: You're not showing enough code to say why a new list should have `list` as its metatable rather than the default `table`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### So why does the list table call __index and then assign itself to list.__index?

Nowhere in your code does the list table *call* `__index`. The assignment part however is a common Lua idiom (aka. hack) to save some memory. Conceptually there are 4 different kinds of tables involved:

1. list objects (the tables created via `{length=0}` in your code)
2. a metatable (containing an `__index` field) that modifies the behavior of list objects when you try to access non-existing fields in the object
3. the `list` class, which holds all the methods for list objects (like the `push` method), and also serves as a constructor for list objects
4. a metatable (containing a `__call` field) for the `list` class, so that you can call the `list` table as if it were a function

   [image: list objects separate metatable and index table]

As metatable fields always start with two underscores (`__`), and normal methods usually don't, you can put metatable fields and normal methods side by side into a single table without conflict. And this is what happened here. The `list` class table also serves as metatable for list objects. So using this trick you can save the memory you would normally need for the separate metatable (the size in bytes for Lua 5.2 on an x86-64 Linux is shown in square brackets in the table title bars, btw.):

[image: list objects with merged metatable and index table]

### Does Window.mt simply create a table?

No, `{}` creates a table. However, this new table is saved under key `"mt"` in the `Window` table, probably to give users of this `Window` "class" direct access to the metatable that is used for window objects. Given only the code you showed this is not strictly necessary, and you could have used a local variable instead.

### Why do we need Window = {} as a namespace here?

In principle, you could store `Window.mt`, `Window.new`, and `Window.prototype` separately, but that would get cumbersome if you have multiple "classes" like `Window`. This way you can avoid name clashes, and using the `Window` "class" looks nicer.

Another reason might be that `require` can only return a single value from a module definition, and if you want to export multiple values (like `new`, `mt`, and `prototype`) from a module, you need a table to wrap them together (or use global variables, but that is considered bad style).