# Lua and C++ Binding - What does this line mean?

Tags: c++, binding, lua, lua-api

The following code is to bind a C++ class to Lua.

```
void registerPerson(lua_State *lua, Person *person)
{
    //We assume that the person is a valid pointer
    Person **pptr = (Person**)lua_newuserdata(lua, sizeof(Person*));
    *pptr = person; //Store the pointer in userdata. You must take care to ensure 
                    //the pointer is valid entire time Lua has access to it.

    if (luaL_newmetatable(lua, "PersonMetaTable")) //This is important. Since you 
        //may invoke it many times, you should check, whether the table is newly 
        //created or it already exists
    {
        //The table is newly created, so we register its functions
        lua_pushvalue(lua, -1);  
        lua_setfield(lua, -2, "__index");

        luaL_Reg personFunctions[] = {
            "getAge", lua_Person_getAge,
            nullptr, nullptr
        };
        luaL_register(lua, 0, personFunctions);
    }

    lua_setmetatable(lua, -2);
}
```

The above code is from an answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22515908/using-straight-lua-how-do-i-expose-an-existing-c-class-objec-for-use-in-a-lua). It binds a C++ class(Person) to Lua. As you can see it, this function

Creates a new user data and pushes it to the top of the stack. Stores the person pointer in the user data.

Creates a metatable using luaL_newmetatable named "PersonMetaTable" and by now the metatable should be at the top of the stack.

According to the documentation, the `lua_pushvalue` function copies the element at the given index to the top of the stack. But here, the function is called with the argument -1, which I think copies the metatable (as it is on the top of the stack), am I correct?

Why should the metatable be copied? What is the purpose of this line?

```
lua_pushvalue(lua, -1);
```

Comment: You normally use two tables: one metatable containing metamethods (all starting with `__`, just `__index` in this case) and an index table which contains the methods (usually all *without* `__`). To save memory you can merge those two. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27519842/confusion-of-using-notation-with-index-and-namespace-in-lua/27525100#27525100) (minus the metatable containing the `__call` metamethod).

Answer (score 2):

`lua_setfield` pops the assigned value off the stack, so you need the `lua_pushvalue` to duplicate the metatable reference so that it's not lost when setting the `__index` table.

```
Begin: [Person*, metatable]
lua_pushvalue: [Person*, metatable, metatable] <- metatable duplicated and pushed onto stack
lua_setfield: [Person*, metatable] <- metatable duplicate is popped. metatable.__index = metatable
lua_setmetatable: [Person*] <- metatable is popped. getmetatable(Person*) = metatable
```