# Lua, which way to do class-table and instantiation?

Tags: class, lua, instantiation, lua-table, metatable

The question originated from http://tylerneylon.com/a/learn-lua/
The tutorial includes codes:

```
Dog = {dog1 = 'original dog class'}
function Dog.new(self, ... )
    newObj = {sound = 'woof'}
    self.__index = self
    return setmetatable(newObj, self)
end

function Dog.makeSound(self, ... )
    print('I say' .. self.sound)
end

print('Dog=', Dog)
print('Dog.metatable=', getmetatable(Dog))  -- this will output nothing

myDog = Dog.new(Dog)
print('\nmyDog=', myDog)
print('myDog.metatable=', getmetatable(myDog))
myDog.makeSound(myDog)
```

This is the result of the above codes in tutorial:

```
wirelessprvnat-172-17-106-141:Programming frankhe$ th test2.lua
Dog=  {
  makeSound : function: 0x0a6cec20
  dog1 : "original dog class"
  new : function: 0x0a6cec00
}
Dog.metatable=  nil 

myDog=  {
  sound : "woof"
}
myDog.metatable=  {
  makeSound : function: 0x0a6cec20
  __index : 
    {
      makeSound : function: 0x0a6cec20
      __index : 
        {
          makeSound : function: 0x0a6cec20
          __index : 
            {
              makeSound : function: 0x0a6cec20
              __index : 
                {
                  makeSound : function: 0x0a6cec20
                  __index : {...}
                  dog1 : "original dog class"
                  new : function: 0x0a6cec00
                }
              dog1 : "original dog class"
              new : function: 0x0a6cec00
            }
          dog1 : "original dog class"
          new : function: 0x0a6cec00
        }
      dog1 : "original dog class"
      new : function: 0x0a6cec00
    }
  dog1 : "original dog class"
  new : function: 0x0a6cec00
}
I saywoof
```

[One additional photo to depict the question more clearly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2oOM.png)

Although the implementation in tutorial prints ‘I saywoof’ successfully, myDog’s metatable is apparently not as desirable as we expected. Therefore my solution is below (the differences are in Dog.new):

```
function Dog.new(self, ... )
    newObj = {sound = 'woof'}
    return setmetatable(newObj, {__index = self})
end
```

The result of my solution:

```
wirelessprvnat-172-17-106-141:Programming frankhe$ th test2.lua
Dog=  {
  makeSound : function: 0x0d7f2978
  dog1 : "original dog class"
  new : function: 0x0d7f2958
}
Dog.metatable=  nil 

myDog=  {
  sound : "woof"
}
myDog.metatable=  {
  __index : 
    {
      makeSound : function: 0x0d7f2978
      dog1 : "original dog class"
      new : function: 0x0d7f2958
    }
}
I saywoof
```

My code prints 'I saywoof' and has a more precise table structure.
I want to know which implementation is right, the one in tutorial or mine? 
In addition, I want to know why the code in tutorial generates an iterative definition of Dog's metatable.

Comment: What `print` function is producing that output? I don't believe it is getting the that hierarchy correct. I believe your change just creates a new table each time `Dog:new()` is called as opposed to reusing the existing `Dog` table. (Though I agree that `self.__index = self` in the `new` function is odd since you really only need to do that once per class (and not once per-instance since `self` is the class).

Comment: I added a photo to describe the question more properly. The `Print` is just the default print function in lua.

Comment: Both approaches are correct but suboptimal. The one from the tutorial uses a hack to save memory by using the same table for methods *and* metamethods. See first part of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27519842/confusion-of-using-notation-with-index-and-namespace-in-lua/27525100#27525100). Your approach allocates a new metatable for every Dog object. You should allocate the metatable outside of `Dog.new` and re-use it.

Comment: Stock lua `print` doesn't print tables like that. Ah, `th` appears to be the torch interpreter with a customized `print` function. And I believe it is just getting confused by the table having itself as `__index` and recursing to its maximum depth of four. If you call `setprintlevel` to change that value I bet you'll see it print exactly as many nested levels as you set it to print to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lets look at the structure of table `Dog`, which after construction of a Dog object has a `__index` metamethod set like this:

```
Dog = {}            --> table: 000000000079a510     
Dog.__index = Dog   --> table: 000000000079a510
```

When you print the `Dog` table the the key `__index` has the value of its containing table, which leads to the recursion. Standard Lua doesn't pretty print tables, so this `print` function must stop after ~5 levels (ie: `__index : {...}` where it halts the recursion). As mentioned by @siffiejoe in the comments, this is a technique to use a single table for both object methods and metamethods.

Concerning which implementation is right; there are many ways to create objects in Lua. The example class, while not wrong, does IMHO needlessly use global variables. Its implementation leaks out into the global environment through `Dog` and `newObj`. Not much of a problem in isolation, but when part of a larger program this can be a source of hard to find bugs. An alternative technique is to implement your class as a module. Use local variables for the implementation and export only what is needed to instantiate new objects.

For example, lets look at a refactor of the `Dog` class:

```
-- class: dog.lua
--
local Dog = {}     -- the objects implementation
Dog.__index = Dog  -- also, its own metatable

-- instantiate a Dog object:
local function new(name, sound)
    local self = {
        name = name,
        sound = sound or 'woof'
    }
    return setmetatable(self, Dog)
end

-- implement object methods:
function Dog.say(self)
    print(('<%s> says: %s'):format(self.name, self.sound))
end

-- implement object metamethods (unique to Dog objects):
function Dog.__tostring(self)
    return ('Dog: %s'):format(self.name)
end

-- module exports:
return {
    new = new;       -- Dog constructor
    __object = Dog;  -- Dog object table/metatable
}
```

The module exports a constructor that knows how to build a `Dog` object without the need for a global object.

```
-- original example:
myDog = Dog.new(Dog)  --> must pass in the global Dog table to create new objects

-- vs --

-- refactored example:
local Dog = require 'dog'   --> Dog object factory
local myDog = Dog.new()     --> instantiate new Dog
```

Inheritance can be handled by chaining metatables and calling the parents constructor in the `new` function:

```
-- class: colorfuldog.lua
--
local Dog = require 'dog'   -- import the parent class

local ColorfulDog = setmetatable({}, Dog.__object)  -- inherit from Dog
ColorfulDog.__index = ColorfulDog                   -- also, its own metatable

-- instantiate a new ColorfulDog object:
local function new(name, sound, color)
    local self = Dog.new(name, sound)  -- construct the parent first
    self.color = color
    return setmetatable(self, ColorfulDog)
end

-- implement or override object methods:
function ColorfulDog.lookat(self)
    print(('<%s> looks: %s'):format(self.name, self.color))
end

-- implement object metamethods (unique to ColorfulDog objects):
function ColorfulDog.__tostring(self)
    return ('ColorfulDog: %s'):format(self.name)
end

-- module exports
return {
    new = new;
    __object = ColorfulDog;
}
```

This way each class is encapsulated in its own module which doesn't leak implementation details into the global environment.

```
-- script: test.lua
--
local Dog = require 'dog'
local ColorfulDog = require 'colorfuldog'

local d1 = Dog.new 'Rover'
local d2 = Dog.new('Max', 'arf!')
local d3 = ColorfulDog.new('Lassie', 'ruff', 'brown')

d1:say()  -- sugar for d1.say(d1)
d2:say()
d3:say()  -- inherited from Dog
d3:lookat()

print(d1, d2, d3)
```

Running the above outputs:

```
$ lua test.lua
<Rover> says: woof
<Max> says: arf!
<Lassie> says: ruff
<Lassie> looks: brown
Dog: Rover      Dog: Max        ColorfulDog: Lassie
```

Like I said previously, there are many *many* ways to create classes in Lua, this is just an example of one. However you choose to implement objects, its still a good practice to keep the global environment clean.

Comment: Hi Adam, thank you very much for this very detailed answer! I have another question on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37377830/lua-attempt-to-index-field-parent-a-nil-value  I think you are very likely to be able to answer my question. So please have a look when you are free, thank you!

Comment: Thanks heaps for this succinct example intro into classes and inheritance in lua!