# need help understanding metamethod of table being set to that table

Tags: lua

I'm not sure what the point of setting the metamethod of Stack to Stack is.

I've looked around but none of the explanations made too much sense. I get that sometimes instances may need to fall back on Stack for any missing methods but was hoping for a clearer explanation.

`Stack = {}
Stack.__index = Stack`

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27519842/3677376

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have a "2d vector" "class" which has a `.x` and a `.y`. You write a `dotproduct` function for them:

```
function dotproduct(a, b)
    return a.x * b.x + a.y * b.y
end
```

The simplest way to let you write `foo:dot(bar)` would be to put a `.dot` property on every new instance:

```
-- Make a "V2" namespace
local V2 = {}
function V2.new(x, y)
    return {
        x = x,
        y = y,

        -- Attach any methods to the object, also
        dot = dotproduct,
    }
end
```

However, as the number of methods grows, this gets worse for two reasons. One is that your objects get larger -- even though you only need to hold two numbers on each vector, most of the hashtable is functions which are always the same! Another is that multiple constructors get difficult because you need to duplicate the work in each constructor.

A solution to this is the `__index` metatable. Instead of copying each method onto each new object, you can just point to where to find "missing" methods as they needed:

```
V2.dot = dotproduct
function V2.new(x, y)
    return setmetatable({x = x, y = y}, {__index = V2})
end
```

This design has a small drawback. First, you're allocating a new metatable in addition to every table, which is a waste of memory (all of the metatables are the same). Second, you don't have an opportunity to override other methods without growing this new metatable (the same annoyance from before).

So, we just make `V2` be the *single*  metatable:

```
V2.__index = V2
function V2.new(x, y)
   return setmetatable({x = x, y = y}, V2)
end
```